# How to find the distance between two arms of a hairpin resonator?

Tags: microwave, microstrip, ads

In this picture I want to find the value of W_cap(the distance between two arms of hairpin resonator). I have the length, width, quality factor and coupling co-efficient of the resonator.
[image]

Comment: You didn't mention the operating frequency.

Comment: Operating frequency 300MHz.

Comment: In the past I have calculated the approximate dimensions based on a quarter wave stub and, to tweak the response physically, I've made the two vertical arms solderable and the shorting section I've made from a short wire (or even an SMD low nH inductor). With the circuit still on (battery powered) I've used a soldering iron to shift the bridge to get the right response.